# Angular check for one or more ng-if statements are true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have a situation where I am building a dynamic table where cells contain an aggregate of data using several `ng-if` statements. Basically I need to know if none of the if statements are true so I can do another `ng-if`.

This is a simplified example of what I am doing. There are about 20 columns with different aggregated results.

```html
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="record in data">
        <td>
            <span ng-if="record.some_number > 0 && record.type == 'SomeType'">{{data1}}</span>
            <span ng-if="record.age >= 20 && record.age <= 50 && record.gender == 'MALE'">{{data2}}</span>
            <span ng-if="(record.age <= 20 || record.age >= 50) && record.gender == 'FEMALE'">{{data3}}</span>
            <span ng-if="!(record.some_number > 0 && record.type == 'SomeType') && !(record.age >= 20 && record.age <= 50 && record.gender == 'MALE') && !((record.age <= 20 || record.age <= 50) && record.gender == 'FEMALE')">{{data4}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

I can't use a ng-switch because the conditions are completely different. This is an aggregate of data, not if/else. I prefer a different approach to just adding a '!' to each condition in another span because some of my aggregates contain many conditions and some of the if statements are not trivial. There are also many aggregate cells so maintenance on the overly complicated 'else' conditions would be a nightmare.

Ideally I would love to just be able to assign a single variable to true on any `ng-if` statement being true. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should create a variable on `$scope` which you can map to your conditions, rather than doing all the checks in the JS.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I want to do but am not sure how to do that using ng-if statements. I assume the only way to do that is in my controller. That isn't ideal because then I have to maintain my conditions in two places.

Comment: I'll show you an example in an answer

Comment: I guess I could just create $scope variables for all of my conditions and then use those in my html page. I was hoping to keep it all on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about it being a best practice, but I believe you should have all your logic in your JS, and the HTML should just be a template which reflects the state of the scope you're displaying.

In this manner, your conditions would ALWAYS be checked in your JS.

**UPDATE:** based on new content:

So you have data and what it looks like is you need to process it first, else your app performance will suffer with an overload of watchers.

First: simplify your HTML, all the logic like `record.some_number > 0 && record.type == 'SomeType'"` belongs in the JS.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="record in data"> 
        <td>
            <span ng-repeat="item in record.dataToShow" ng-bind-html='item'></span> // now you just repeat the data that has been processed
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Second: do the processing in your JavaScript in a loop.

```
$scope.data = [ some array with lots of stuff ];

for( var idx in $scope.data ){
    var record = $scope.data[ idx ]; // assuming JSON object
    var dataToShow = []; // store your data(s) in an array

    // if a condition is met, push your data onto the array
    if( record.some_number > 0 && record.type == 'SomeType' ){
        dataToShow.push( data1 );
    }
    if( record.age >= 20 && record.age <= 50 && record.gender == 'MALE' ){
        dataToShow.push( data2 );
    }
    // continue processing conditions

    if( dataToShow.length === 0 ){ // none have been true if array is empty
        // do something
    }
    record.dataToShow = dataToShow;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZPbui4rLwGGVVD4B90b9?p=preview

Comment: Is there no way to do this on the html page? That is a lot of refactoring in my application.

Comment: Not really, sorry for the trouble, I hate to say it, but there should be very little logic in the HTML if any. If you have to refactor the page, then you should do it, that would make it more easy to maintain later.

Comment: The other difficulty is that these are all part of a HTML table using ng-repeat.

Comment: What's the difficulty as compared to any other tag? You have to post your code somewhere in order for me to understand. I assume that one row controls the display of another with an ng-click, but I would still stand by my statement of putting the controls in JS. If it's logic, then it belongs on the programming side (JS) not the markup side (HTML)

Comment: I just mean that these conditions represent a cell inside of a table for a single record. If I do a scope variable I would have to do an array of conditions or similar, one for each row and all of the conditions for all of the cells in that row. I will update my code to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Get a scope function to decide how to handle ng-if for various conditions.

```
<span ng-if="showHideCell(this)">{{data1}}</span>
<span ng-if="showHideCell(this)">{{data2}}</span>
```

And in your controller..

```
$scope.showHideCell = function(ele) {

    //Your complex condition here

    return decition;   // true or false
}
```

---

If the application is critical for throughput and has a lot of controls, I would suggest using SoluableNonagon's method in his answer. There every digestion cycle would only check for a variable.

Comment: I would not recommend assigning a function to an ng-if, while this does work it also runs on every digest cycle rather than just an event.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in https://github.com/zachsnow/ng-elif, which is a pretty good if-elseif-else extension to angular's ng-if.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic method in your controller to check for your conditions on elements, while you can have another one, which will apply to all of them, essentially calling the generic method mentioned earlier.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3u0aq6?p=preview) is a plunk doing something similar to what you want to achieve, might give you an idea.

What I do here, is to have for example, two arrays, one with odd values and one with even only values. I have a method `condition` on the controller which accepts a value (gets the value of array from `ng-repeat` loop) and an `all` method which calls the `condition`.

```
  $scope.condition = function(element, value) {
    // Just returns true for even values

    if (typeof value === "number")
      return value % 2 == 0;
    else if (value instanceof Array) {
      return value.every(function(item) {
        return item % 2 == 0;
      });
    }

  }

  $scope.all = function(element, value) {
    return $scope.condition(element, value);
  }
```

You can work on a similar approach.